# Find verbs in a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I'm parsing a txt file (called `text1`) in Python. My idea is to identify all the verbs in the text. So I thought about creating another txt file in which to put all the verbs.

Now, what code should I use to compare verbs.txt and locate them in text1?

Comment: You can probably read the `verbs.txt` file to a dictionary with keys as the verbs and values zero. Now iterate over `text1.txt` word by word and if the word exists in the dictionary, (checking which is approximately linear time) and if it is present, increase the value by 1. This way you would also get a count of those verbs too. (Well ofcourse this is in pure python and there are libraries like nltk to do this)

Comment: Yes I'm using NLTK, so is there a simpler method? Could you tell me the exact code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is without `NLTK`:

```
dct = {}
with open("verbs.txt") as vb:
    for line in vb:
        for word in line.strip().split():
            dct[word] = 0

with open("text1.txt") as ip:
    for line in ip:
        for word in line.strip().split():
            if word in dct: 
                dct[word] += 1

print(dct)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! But in nltk is there an easier way to do this, without creating a text with verbs, adjectives, pronouns, etc every time?

Comment: @Victory74, yes there is, but this might just do fine if your files are not too large. If it helped, you should consider accepting the answer :)